# Jekyll .md to html

Tags: jekyll

Does Jekyll converts all `.markdown` files to HTML in my `_posts` folder every time i'm starting the server or it convert only modified or newly added `.md` posts? If yes is it a possible to skip not modified `.md` files to convert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about when you're running it locally in development or during the build?

Take a look at the [build command options](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/#build-command-options), there's:

> Incremental build
>
> Enable the experimental incremental build feature. Incremental build
> only re-builds posts and pages that have changed, resulting in
> significant performance improvements for large sites, but may also
> break site generation in certain cases.